# Reading multiple blocks from a CoAP block-wise transfer on SIM7080G modem

Tags: network-programming, at-command, rfc, coap, sim7600

### Problem:

The SIM7080G modem can detect there are multiple blocks in a CoAP response from a server but is only able to read the first block.

AT commands used:

```
AT+CCOAPINIT
AT+CCOAPURL="coap://coap.mydomain.no:5683"
AT+CCOAPPARA="CODE",1,uri-path,0,"certificate/fcd15ca1600f045/ca",token,0,"UBXTRDGZALKNPME"

Writing: AT+CCOAPACTION
Reponse: +CCOAPACTION: 0,0
OK
+CCOAPRECV: 8671,532,512    <- Package size of 532, payload size 512, This is correct for the first package

Writing: AT+CCOAPACTION=4
Response: AT+CCOAPACTION=4
+CCOAPACTION: 4,2,8671 <- 2 blocks on queue
OK
Writing: AT+CCOAPHEAD=8671,1
Response: AT+CCOAPHEAD=8671,1
+CCOAPHEAD: 1,1,0,8,2.05,8671,554258545244475A,50,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,0:1:512,,619 <- block 1
OK

Writing: AT+CCOAPREAD=8671
Response: AT+CCOAPREAD=8671
+CCOAPREAD: 512, first 512 characters of the looong string sent by the server...
OK
+CCOAPRECV: 8671,532,512

(repeat AT+CCOAPACTION=4, AT+CCOAPHEAD, and AT+CCOAPREAD for subsequent blocks)
```

Repeating the commands only reads out the first block on the receive queue.

### Expected response:

The modem should be able to read out all blocks (2 in this example) from the CoAP response either by looping the commands or by specifying which block to read.

### Investigated documentation:

```
SIM7070_SIM7080_SIM7090 Series_AT Command Manual v1.04
SIM7070_SIM7080_SIM7090 Series_CoAP(S)_Application Note v1.03
```

### Question:

Which AT commands and sequence are required to read multiple or a specific block from the queue (e.g., block 2) on the SIM7080G modem when using CoAP?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear:
CoAP comes in the meantime with two extensions addressing larger payload:

- the traditional one is RFC 7959, which converts the transfer of a larger payload in common standard requests with smaller payload (multiple request/response exchanges).
- a different one, RFC 9177.
- and you may use CoAP over TCP, RFC 8323

The issue will be, what the modem supports. I guess, with RFC 7959 you may have the best chance, but that may be wrong.